# Sum of each individual row in a 2D Array

Tags: java

I'd like to know how to print each individual row's sum in a 2D Array instead 
of summing each row as the loop progresses.

```
int sum  = 0;
int[][] nums = {{16, 29, 31, 65, 67},
    {28, 30, 39, 59, 70},
    {1, 42, 47, 64, 70}};

int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < nums[i].length; j++) {
        sum+= nums[i][j];  
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums[i]));
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: In general, if you want to sum each row in the 2D array, you have to iterate over that row, unless you somehow have the total stored elsewhere already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print the sum of each row you need to reset `sum` to 0 every time you start to sum a new row.

```
int[][] nums = {{16, 29, 31, 65, 67}, {28, 30, 39, 59, 70}, {1, 42, 47, 64, 70}};

for (int row = 0; row < nums.length; row++) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int col = 0; col < nums[row].length; col++)
        sum += nums[row][col];
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums[row]));
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: I was so damn close. I knew I had to reset sum but couldn't figure out where to place the code. Thank you